# How to delete remote branch on sourcetree?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to delete the local and remote feature branch. After deleted the local branch, I deleted the remote branch by right-click the branch under `remote/origin/feature`. The branch is disappeared on my local and remote branch (origin), but still exist in other user's sourcetree. How to solve this? Thanks!

ps: I want other users cant see the branch as well. I guess the reason is I pushed the `feature` to `develop`. How can I get back the branch to my remote `branch` origin in order to reverse commit first?

Comment: To the Stackoverflow admins: the question is with regards to how you do this in the SourceTree app, not how you do it on the command line in git.  This question should be re-opened, I have an answer to provide.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete like this `git push <remote_name> --delete <branch_name>`

For example: `git push origin --delete feature/test-branch`

Where:
- origin is name remote repository
- feature/test-branch is name your branch that will be deleted

Comment: Thanks! but I have already removed in my sourcetree. This error occur when I try your command in terminal. error: unable to delete 'feature/module': remote ref does not exist

Comment: It seems like the branch is already deleted remotely. If others are still seeing the branch remotely, it's because they haven't done a `git fetch`, so they're looking at an outdated version of the remote.

Answer (score 0):

if I correctly understand your question, try using this in your terminal

```
git push <remote_name> --delete <branch_name>
```

Where  is  is branch you want to delete. For example:

```
git push origin --delete feature
```

Comment: Thanks! but I have already removed in my sourcetree. This error occur when I try your command in terminal. error: unable to delete 'feature/module': remote ref does not exist

Comment: maybe you should recreate your branch locally, then git push --set-upstream <branch_name> and then try again to delete?